# Spring form login, multiple roles with form issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

Ok so I have my login page on localhost/login there I have two forms with the same action which is /login (for now). I am trying to accomplish this scenario:

User is on the login page, he is offered a choice between two forms 1. offers a form which will redirect him to /employees/home 2. offers form for /administrator/home. Keep in mind that user that has ADMIN role can log to the /employees/home as well

The application has two roles ADMIN and EMP.

I want the web app to be able to grant authority correctly for each user and redirect him where it is needed. I am able to do this with a single role but as soon as i put in another one, the app starts to lose it. This is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.
        jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}


protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
    authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
        .authenticated().and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login/administrator").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and().logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/employee/**").hasAuthority("EMP")
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/employee/home")
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and().logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
        ;
/*  http.
    authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
        .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and().logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");*/
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
       .ignoring()
       .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
}
```

Queries

```
spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, active from user where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?
```

Main login controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value={"/","/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Repositories and services work, they are tested with a single role. I figure that it is the issue with SecurityConfiguration class. NOTE*I have tried making several configuration classes with different orders, that did not work as well.

Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect redirect the different page based on the user's role?

Comment: Yes, for example try to log in as an administrator i got the credentials with u:email@gmail.com p:password r: ADMIN i get redirected to localhost/administrator/home which is accessible only for users with ADMIN role. Or i try to log in as an User/employee u:emp@gmail.com p:password r:EMP i get redirected to localhost/employee/home but this one would be accessible for ADMIN role as well

Comment: Then you can achieve by custom authenticationsuccesshandler

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I have never dealt with successHandler class. Do you have an example or a link to a guide how to do it?

Comment: I think i found it. Will tell you if i succeed. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around managed to resolve the issue as Sankar stated with custom success handler class.

```
public class CustomSuccessHandler
  implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
....
protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        boolean isEmp= false;
        boolean isAdmin = false;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
         = authentication.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
            if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("EMPLOYEE")) {
                isUser = true;
                break;
            } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ADMIN")) {
                isAdmin = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isEmp) {
            return "/employee/home";
        } else if (isAdmin) {
            return "/admin/home";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
....
}
```

But at the end, decided to scrap the logic and switch to a single log in form which leads to landing page from where the user can choose where to go.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
        authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/landing").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","EMPLOYEE")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employee/**").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/landing")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    }
```

based on the user's role links to the /employee/home or /admin/home are disabled, or not.